# IE not rendering CSS text correctly - background-clip

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, text

My problem is in regards to IE and how it is displaying my background clipped text.

Normally (chrome/ff/etc) my code renders this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9lio.png

However in IE it is rendering like this:

http://puu.sh/3kJOx.png

My code is as follows:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="centerArt">
        Hi, Visitor!
    </div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#centerArt{
font-family:"Arial", Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 100px;
line-height: 150px;
background-color: #565656;
color: transparent;
text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
 -webkit-background-clip: text;
 -moz-background-clip: text;
      background-clip: text;}
```

Is there any way to make IE behave? :)

Thanks!

Comment: Which versions of IE are you attempting this with? Please be more specific. I know for certain that IE6-9 do not support this feature. IE9 only supports background-clip: border-box | padding-box | content-box. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj127314(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

`background-clip: text` is not supported in IE, valid property values are only `border-box`, `padding-box` and `content-box`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj127314(v=vs.85).aspx

You could try using   `@supports (-webkit-background-clip: text)` with a fallback for other browsers.

Answer (score -1):

IE doesnt support `color: transparent` value defined. Try using

`font-size: 0;` or add IE hack `background:none\9;`

Comment: Seems you're right about that variable, are there any other changes needed?

Comment: Of course IE supports `color: transparent`, but what it doesn’t support is `background-clip` – and therefor no text is visible at all.

Comment: Is it impossible to display text that looks like this in IE then?

Comment: @CBoe IE doesnt support color:transparent,please do some research before down voting.

Comment: @KashifRaza, sorry, but you are just _wrong_ here :-P Have a look in IE please: http://jsfiddle.net/EW7bn/ You won’t see anything between _Foo_ and _bar_, _because_ the text color is transparent.